# Delete old files except for a certain file. Directory is being deleted

Tags: powershell

I have a script that deletes files older than 14 days unless the file is called `test.dll`.

The problem is that if the folder is older than 14 day but the file is young, say two days old, the folder and file are being deleted. How can I fix this so the folder is not deleted if the file exists?

The file can be in any sub directory in the tree. Basically I want it to delete all files and folders older than 14 days except `test.dll` whereever it lives in the sub directory structure.

Here is the script I was using:

```
$Now = Get-Date
$Days = "14"
$TargetFolder = "E:\Web2\testdir"
$Extension = "*.*"
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)

#---- get files based on lastwrite filter and specified folder ----!
$Files = Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -Exclude "test.dll" -Recurse |
         Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}

#---- For each file in $TargetFolder folder, run a foreach loop and delete the file
if ($Files) {
    foreach ($File in $Files) {
        if ($File -ne $null) {
            Write-Host "Deleting File $File" -ForegroundColor "DarkRed"
            Remove-Item $File.FullName -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
        } else {
            Write-Host "No more files to delete!" -ForegroundColor "Green"
        }
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "There are no files older than $Days days old in $TargetFolder" -ForegroundColor "Green"
}
```

Comment: Ok - I add -not $_.PSIsContainer to this line: $Files = Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -Exclude "upd.info.raf" -Recurse | Where {(-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite")}

Comment: This worked well. The file was maintained in the sub directories but all old files are gone. The only problem is I'm left with thousands of empty directories. Is there a way to remove the empty directories as well? The ones that meet the 14 day old criteria?

Answer (score 3):

Pass the `-File` parameter to `Get-ChildItem` when you collect a list of your files:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -File -Exclude "test.dll" -Recurse
```

Comment: Prior to PowerShell v3 use `... | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }` instead of the `-File` parameter.

Comment: To remove the empty folders I added this code below the last else in the script. I don't know if this is the cleanest way but it seems to work.